# Surface constructed using curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Suppose that $E$ and $F$ are two complex compact Riemann surfaces with genus greater or equal than $2$.
Set $$S=E \times F$$ the surface composed by the cartesian product of thees curves. 
What can i say about the intersection number $E.F$ and the self intersection $E^2$ or $F^2$?

Comment: Draw a picture of what this surface looks like. Where are $E$ and $F$ in your picture? How many points of intersection do they have?

Comment: Inside $E\times F$ the curves $E$ and $F$ meet just once, transversally.

Comment: i think that $E^2=0$ and $E.F=1$ but i would like to write a formal proof

Comment: how can i show this?

Comment: @dario Compute $E^2$ by writing it as $p^{-1}(y) \cdot p^{-1}(y)$ with $y$ some point in $F$ and $p$ the projection $E\times F\to F$.

Comment: is it enough to say that, for example, if $p_1$ and $p_2$ are two distinct points on $F$ and $\pi_F$ the projection on the curve $F$ then $\pi^{-1}_F(p_1)$ has no intersection points with $\pi^{-1}F(p_2)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate E.F by taking curves representing the classes [E] and [F] which intersect transversely and counting their points of intersection.

In particular, pick points $e \in E$ and $f \in F$ and take $E \times \{f\}$ and $\{e\} \times F$.  Clearly these only meet at the single point $(e, f)$, and moreover it's easy to calculate the tangent spaces and see that the intersection is transverse.  So $E.F = 1$.

For $E.E$, take points $f, f' \in F$ and consider the curves $E \times \{f\}$ and $E \times \{f'\}$.  These don't meet at all, so they surely meet transversely.  Therefore $E^2 = 0$.